# Ajax DATA changes sorting

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, wordpress, sorting

Im doing a AJAX call with my Wordpress site.  It works all perfect except for the ORDER (sort) of the data that is coming out the SUCCESS function.

If I `print_r ($service)` I validate the correct custom order that I want

But after is send using:

(PHP FILE)

```
public function closest_services() {
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    $servicios_repetidos = $_POST['servicios_repetidos'];
    
    $lat        = $_POST['latitud'];
    $lng        = $_POST['longitud'];
    $categoria  = array();
    $unit       = $_POST['unit'];
    $distancia  = $_POST['radius'];
    
    if ( $unit == 'km' ) { $earth_radius = 6371.009 / 1.609344 ; }
    elseif ( $unit == 'mi' ) { $earth_radius = 3958.761; }
    
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT DISTINCT
            p.ID AS service_ID,
            p.post_title AS service_title,
            map_lat.meta_value AS locLat,
            map_lng.meta_value AS locLong,
            
            
            %f * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( %f - map_lat.meta_value ) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
            + COS( %f * pi()/180) * COS( map_lng.meta_value * pi()/180) 
            * POWER(SIN(( %f - map_lng.meta_value) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
            AS distance
            
        FROM $wpdb->posts p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta map_lat ON p.ID = map_lat.post_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta map_lng ON p.ID = map_lng.post_id
        WHERE 1 = 1
        AND p.post_type = 'servicios'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND map_lat.meta_key = 'et_meta_latitud'
        AND map_lng.meta_key = 'et_meta_longitud'
        HAVING distance <= %d
        ORDER BY distance DESC",
        $earth_radius,
        $lat,
        $lat,
        $lng,
        $distancia      
    );
    
    $closest_services_query = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    $servicio = array();
    
    foreach ( $closest_services_query as $single_service ):
        
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["service_ID"]            = $single_service->service_ID;
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["meta_fields"]           = get_post_custom( $single_service->service_ID );
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["service_author"]        = get_post_field ( 'post_author' , $single_service->service_ID );
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["service_author_avatar"] = get_avatar( $single_service->service_ID , '64');
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["service_author_url"]    = bp_core_get_user_domain( $single_service->service_ID );           
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["category"]              = get_the_terms( $single_service->service_ID , 'servicios-categoria');
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["service_title"]         = $single_service->service_title;
        
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["thumb_url"]             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $single_service->service_ID ) , 'medium' );
      
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["distancia"]             = $single_service->distance;
        
        $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["precio_servicio_visibilidad"] = get_post_meta( $single_service->service_ID , 'et_meta_precio_visibilidad' , true);
        
        if ( function_exists( 'get_favorites_button' ) ) 
            $servicio[$single_service->service_ID]["favorite_button"] = get_favorites_button( $single_service->service_ID );

    endforeach;
    
    //print_r($servicio);
    wp_send_json($servicio);
    
}
```

(JQUERY FILE)

```
function ajax_mapa () {                 
    var center = map.getCenter();
        
    latitud     = center.lat();
    longitud    = center.lng();
    
    jQuery( "body" ).after( "<div class='loading'>Loading&#8230;</div>" );
                                                
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        
        data: { 
            'action'    : 'closest_services',
            'latitud'   : latitud,
            'longitud'  : longitud,
            'categoria' : categoria,
            'servicios_repetidos' : servicios_repetidos,
            'unit'      : 'km',
            'radius'    : 15
        },      
         
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { // Si todo salio bien se ejecuta esto
            
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            
            var servicios = [];
            var precio;
            var moneda;
            var url_imangen;
            var html_marker;
            
            
            
            jQuery.each( data, function( id_servicio, info_servicio ) { ... ...});
     } ... ...
     ...
 }) ...
   } ...
```

The LOG from DATA shows the object ordered by the KEY VALUE instead the custom order that was send before.

If I check the LOG from `jqXHR.responseText`  it have the RIGHT order that I want, so basically the data is being received fine, but something is changing the order.

So, the question is, does anybody knows why is DATA being sorted by KEY VALUE, and how I can fix this?

(LOG of jqXHR WITH CORRECT ORDER - by Distance )

> "{"144":
>
> {"service_ID":"144","distancia":"6.043960511486238"},"110":{"service_ID":"110","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"112":{"service_ID":"112","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"113":{"service_ID":"113","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"114":{"service_ID":"114","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"119":{"service_ID":"119","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"145":{"service_ID":"145","distancia":"6.040024571156195"},"194":{"service_ID":"194","distancia":"5.025501693483518"},"163":{"service_ID":"163","distancia":"4.985331564912346"},"161":{"service_ID":"161","distancia":"1.3274942401635288"}}"

(LOG of DATA WITH INCORRECT ORDER - by KEY ID )

> Object { 110: Object,  112: Object,  113: Object,  114: Object,  119:
> Object,  144: Object,  145: Object,  161: Object,  163: Object,  194:
> Object }

Thanks

Comment: if you can show your query building approach and ajax request in details then it will be more easier to give a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @AbuMuaz just edited the code with the PHP and JQUERY functions that are being used.

Comment: You are mutating the data variable inside the success function, on the $.each part, can you show that piece of code as well?

Comment: @ggderas yes I can add this too, but the console.log( DATA ) with the incorrect order comes BEFORE the $.each, so shouldn't it be in the correct order before going into the $.each ?

Comment: @CarlosCarmona not really, array are objects thus any change will be reference to the same variable regardless of where you're printing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if is the best solution, but I manage to make it work by converting the OBJECT to an Array and then sorting the Array.

Basically I added this code:

```
/* ********************** */
// ordeno por distancia
/* ********************** */
var arr = jQuery.map(data, function(value, key){
    return value
});

function SortByName(a, b){
    var aName = a.distancia;
    var bName = b.distancia; 

    return ((aName > bName) ? -1 : ((aName < bName) ? 1 : 0));
}

arr.sort(SortByName);
/* ********************** */
```

Just before de `jQuery.each( arr , function( id_servicio, info_servicio ) { ... ...});` function